# extract data from mongo wire protocol packets

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, wireshark, packet-capture

I need to extract information from Mongo packets, but I don't found a simple way to do this.
In the figure there is an example of the mongo packets that I use.

[Mongo Wire Protocol Packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O85U.png)

In particular I would like to collect the data indicated as "prod1" and "23.22".

I've use pyshark library with pyshark.FileCapture('capture.pcap',use_json=True), but I can get the data only with a series of nested loops.

Is there a simple way, with the use of a tool or a specific library (also in different language of python), to extract these informations?

Comment: Why do you not use `pymongo` and read directly as `json`?

Comment: Can I use pymongo to extract mongo packets informations in pcap file?


I have an application that comunicates with a Mongo Dabatase.
I use tcpdump to capture the packets that go from the application to the database and I need to extract the information contained within them.

Comment: I meant you can access directly to mono db with `pymongo`. Thus there would not be need to read tcpdump packets.